# Is there a way to mock Facter::Core::Execution.execute output in ruby?

Tags: ruby, testing, mocking, puppet, facter

I have a custom fact in ruby that uses `Facter::Core::Execution.execute` to execute a system command and sets the fact to true or false based on the output of the execute command. Is there a way I could mock the output of the execute command to test it?

Comment: What testing framework are you using?

Comment: @maxpleaner I can use rspec or pytest

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using rspec:

```
expect(Facter::Core::Execution).to receive(:execute).and_return(true)
```